# How do i get toggle working for the FAQ dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I'm trying to get this FAQ to collapse and expand on click, but nothing is happening.

I've tried messing with the CSS a little with the pseudo classes, but I haven't tried anything with JS

```js
$('.faq li .question').click(function () {
  $(this).find('.plus-minus-toggle').toggleClass('collapsed');
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.parent-container {
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
}
.faq {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.faq li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.faq .answer {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease, padding-bottom 0.5s ease;
}
.faq li.active .answer {
  max-height: 275px !important;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease, padding-bottom 0.5s ease;
}
.faq .question {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 800;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 20px 0;
  transition: color 0.5s ease;
}
.faq li.active .question {
  color: #2d2d2d;
  transition: color 0.5s ease;
}

.faq .plus-minus-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 21px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 21px;
  left: -40px;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}
.faq .plus-minus-toggle::before, .faq .plus-minus-toggle::after {
  background: #9b1c21;
  content: '';
  height: 5px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 21px;
  transition: transform 500ms ease;
}
.faq .plus-minus-toggle::after {
  transform-origin: center;
}
.faq .plus-minus-toggle.collapsed::after {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.faq .plus-minus-toggle.collapsed::before {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"> 
 <div class="parent-container">
   <ul class="faq">
  <li>
    <h3 class="question">Frequently Asked Question?
   <div class="plus-minus-toggle collapsed"></div>
    </h3>
    <div class="answer">Answer. Donec vitae tellus risus. Aenean sed fermentum risus. Phasellus venenatis 
   ultricies dignissim. Nunc ante lectus, accumsan non porta at. Donec vitae tellus risus. Aenean sed 
   fermentum risus. Phasellus venenatis ultricies dignissim.</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3 class="question">Frequently Asked Question?
   <div class="plus-minus-toggle collapsed"></div>
    </h3>
    <div class="answer">Answer. Donec vitae tellus risus. Aenean sed fermentum risus. Phasellus venenatis 
   ultricies dignissim. Nunc ante lectus, accumsan non porta at. Donec vitae tellus risus. Aenean sed 
   fermentum risus. Phasellus venenatis ultricies dignissim.</div>
  </li>
   </ul>
 </div>  
</div>
```

I'm expecting the "Frequently Asked Question" answer to be collasped, then on click dropdown below the FAQ title for each question. On the click the "plus" sign turns into a dash.

Comment: Seems to work fine in your snippet. What errors are you getting?

Comment: I"m not seeing any errors, actually. It's just not working at all for me

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/treuther/thkjr3Lx/2/

Comment: You're not including jQuery in your fiddle. Include it and again, it works

Comment: Yeah, I just solved for that one, I just threw it in JS Fiddle to send over and it's working there, but not in my full code.Possibly the VERSION of jquery? I'll look at that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following jQuery library version 3.4.1:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
```